# AWS Iot rest api

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, cookies, token, iot

I currently have a sensor sending data to AWS but I'm having issues figuring out the current status. For example, the sensor sends it's most recent status and I would like to view its status via http/s. Im currently trying to via my devices current status via

https://**endpoint**/things/**thingName**/shadow

or

https://something.iot.region.amazonaws.com/things/MyDevice/shadow

The only response I get back is the following.

```
{"message":"Custom Authorizers are not allowed for this
API","traceId":"123432-2343-23423-2343-12132432"}
```

I know that there's some form of authentication but I cannot seem to find any example on how to call these endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

Read the *Authorization* section [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/API_GetThingShadow.html).

> The Thing Shadows service accepts two forms of authentication:
>   Signature Version 4 with IAM credentials or TLS mutual authentication
>   with a client certificate.

It might be easier for you to [use the AWS SDK to retrieve the thing shadow](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iot-data.html#IoTDataPlane.Client.get_thing_shadow).